# Edittext setOnKeyListener working

Tags: android

I add setOnKeyListener to my Edittext to format it.

```
EditText = ₹ 45,000
```

Before KEY DELETE pressed.I want to delete single digit on each delete key press event till first digit (i.e. "4").On first digit deletion it should also delete "₹ " from edittext making it blank.I written following code but i have to manually delete upto ₹.

Log File:

```
10-02 18:01:08.360    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Before Replace =﹕ ₹ 45,000
10-02 18:01:08.361    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/After Replace =﹕ 45000
10-02 18:01:08.361    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Length =﹕ 5
10-02 18:01:08.488    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Before Replace =﹕ ₹ 45,00
10-02 18:01:08.488    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/After Replace =﹕ 4500
10-02 18:01:08.488    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Length =﹕ 4
10-02 18:01:25.297    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Before Replace =﹕ ₹ 4,500
10-02 18:01:25.297    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/After Replace =﹕ 4500
10-02 18:01:25.297    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Length =﹕ 4
10-02 18:01:25.472    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Before Replace =﹕ ₹ 4,50
10-02 18:01:25.472    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/After Replace =﹕ 450
10-02 18:01:25.472    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Length =﹕ 3
10-02 18:01:27.783    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Before Replace =﹕ ₹ 450
10-02 18:01:27.783    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/After Replace =﹕ 450
10-02 18:01:27.783    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Length =﹕ 3
10-02 18:01:28.017    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Before Replace =﹕ ₹ 45
10-02 18:01:28.017    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/After Replace =﹕ 45
10-02 18:01:28.017    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Length =﹕ 2
10-02 18:01:41.177    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Before Replace =﹕ ₹ 45
10-02 18:01:41.177    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/After Replace =﹕ 45
10-02 18:01:41.177    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Length =﹕ 2
10-02 18:01:41.392    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Before Replace =﹕ ₹ 4
10-02 18:01:41.392    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/After Replace =﹕ 4
10-02 18:01:41.392    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Length =﹕ 1
10-02 18:01:56.121    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Before Replace =﹕ ₹ 4
10-02 18:01:56.121    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/After Replace =﹕ 4
10-02 18:01:56.121    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Length =﹕ 1
10-02 18:01:56.336    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Before Replace =﹕ ₹
10-02 18:03:04.153    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Before Replace =﹕ ₹
10-02 18:03:04.327    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Before Replace =﹕ ₹
10-02 18:03:04.327    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/After Replace =﹕ ₹
10-02 18:03:04.327    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Length =﹕ 1
10-02 18:03:04.616    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Before Replace =﹕ ₹
10-02 18:03:04.616    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/After Replace =﹕ ₹
10-02 18:03:04.616    4731-4731/loginscreen.example.com.girviapp D/Length =﹕ 1
```

Code:

```
 mAmt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() 
{
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                String tmp = mAmt.getText().toString();

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
                {

            /* do something */   
                    Log.d("Before Replace = ",tmp);
                    tmp=tmp.replace("\u20B9 ","");
                    tmp=tmp.replace(" ","");
                    if (tmp.length() > 0  )
                    {
                        tmp=tmp.replace("\u20B9 ","");
                        tmp = tmp.replace(",", "");
                        Log.d("After Replace =  ", tmp.replace("\u20B9 ",""));
                        Log.d("Length = ",String.valueOf(tmp.length()));
                        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "IN"));
                        if(tmp.length()>1) 
                        {

                            DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("\u20B9 " + "##,##,##,##,###");
                            mAmt.setText(myFormatter.format(Integer.parseInt(tmp)));
                            mAmt.setSelection(tmp.length());
                        }


                    }

                }


                mAmt.setSelection(mAmt.getText().length());


                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: on first deletion set string value null in `edittext`

Comment: but where in the code

Comment: check `mAmt.getText().length()==3`. `mAmt.setText(null)` before return.

Comment: Sorry but can u tell in detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
     mAmt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() 
       {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                String tmp = mAmt.getText().toString();

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
                {

            /* do something */   
                    Log.d("Before Replace = ",tmp);
                    tmp=tmp.replace("\u20B9 ","");
                    tmp=tmp.replace(" ","");
                    if (tmp.length() > 0  )
                    {
                        tmp=tmp.replace("\u20B9 ","");
                        tmp = tmp.replace(",", "");
                        Log.d("After Replace =  ", tmp.replace("\u20B9 ",""));
                        Log.d("Length = ",String.valueOf(tmp.length()));
                        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "IN"));
                        if(tmp.length()>1) 
                        {

                            DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("\u20B9 " + "##,##,##,##,###");
                            mAmt.setText(myFormatter.format(Integer.parseInt(tmp)));
                            mAmt.setSelection(tmp.length());
                        }


                    }

                }


                mAmt.setSelection(mAmt.getText().length());

                if(mAmt.getText().length()==3){ 
                  mAmt.setText(null)
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```